# Quick Parts (Autotext) - Word Template

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to make a template for contracts. Within this template I want to use Quick Parts and more specific "Autotext" and "Blank".

Although whenever I choose Autotext Blank it shows "[Type here]".

**My problem is:**

I would like to make a suggestion for what it should display, before writing.
Lets say that it should insted of "[Type here]", it should display "[Enter name here]", but still have the same functionality as the usual.

Is there by any chance that I can modify it, to display what I want it to, but still have the same functionality?

If so, please let me know how.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there isn't a method to dynamically change the text of the built-in Quick Parts. What you can do though is build your own unique text entry fields and save them as AutoText parts.

In a document, place your insertion point at a blank paragraph. Then from Word's Insert tab, locate the Quick Parts menu button and at the bottom of the menu you will see the following:

[image]

Select the Field option and on the Field dialog select a MacroButton field and type the text you want displayed. Press the Field Codes button. In the Fields Code text box, replace `AcceptAllChangesInDoc` with `NoMacro` and click OK.

[image]

You changed the Macro Name to run to a non-existant macro and this will not cause a problem.

Now with the field selected in your document use the AutoText item on the Quick Parts menu that I showed you above to Save the selection as a new unique AutoText entry. The dialog for saving the entry looks like this:

[image]

Give it a unique name, put it in a category or general is just fine, and choose where you are saving it into.

Repeat the process for each unique fill-in part you want.

Comment: I just found out about it 15 minutes ago, continuing to search the web for answers, but thank you for your time :)